# Locale=nl_BE (Dutch Belgium) no longer supported (in iframe like button)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, locale, facebook-iframe

We are a site located in Belgium. We added the 'locale=nl_BE' parameter to our iframe like button so it says like but in the Dutch language (= "vind ik leuk").

This no longer works. When we change the locale to nl_NL (also Dutch language) the like button works again.

When I check the Facebook Internationalization documentation I can't seem to find Belgium or nl_BE, strange right? This worked for months until yeaserday. http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeroenvdb/cw6js/1/

nl_NL (working): https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hln.be%3Futm_source%3Dfacebook%26utm_medium%3Dweb&locale=nl_NL&send=false&layout=box_count&width=0&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=85

nl_BE (not working): https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hln.be%3Futm_source%3Dfacebook%26utm_medium%3Dweb&locale=nl_BE&send=false&layout=box_count&width=0&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=85

Comment: If I login with the account that is admin of the facebook app of this website, I can see the like button. Every other account (or not logged in) can't see the like button.

Comment: Same bug has popped up here also. All the facebook like buttons where we pass nl_BE as locale currently break. As far as I can see the buttons were still up & running a few days ago so I was wondering if they fixed it a few months ago (in April) when you reported the issue and if the bug somehow reappeared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook just closed the bug report I had posted about the nl_BE issue.

"This locale is not currently supported. But you should be able to load the plugin even if a locale is not supported, it will fallback to en_US locale."

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/442881812429427

That's just plain silly. The change I see compared to a few months ago is that (as is mentioned in the comment on the bug) share buttons no longer break when you pass an unsupported locale but fallback to en_US.

They should get their language/locale act together.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a new bug or code change at Facebook.  Similarly, **en_EN** which worked before no longer works.  **en_US** does work.